# Flexbox width to fit square content using aspect ratio

Tags: css, flexbox, aspect-ratio

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to stretch a container width to fit its children.

The children have their height set to that of the container, and `aspect-ratio` set to 1, to make perfect squares. This works fine.

However, it seems the container doesn't recognize their new width. It does so if the child width is set explicitly, but not dynamically using `aspect-ratio`.

Notice how when using aspect ratio, the container seems to think the boxes are actually much smaller than they are. It's as if the container doesn't recognize the change in width at all. I've also included the case where the width has been left unchanged, showing how large the container would be in that case. It seems to correspond to the unchanged width in the aspect-ratio container.

Is this a known issue? Is there a simple solution or workaround, preferably using pure CSS?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 8px;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  column-gap: 16px;
  
  width: fit-content;
}
.button_container {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 8px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: fit-content;
}
.button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  border: 1px solid black;
}
.first_case {
  height: 100%;
  width: 56px;
}
.second_case {
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
.third_case {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Fixed width (this is how it should look)</p>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Text<br/>More text<br/>Lots of text
  </div>
  <div class="button_container">
    <div class="button first_case">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="button first_case">
      B
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<p>Aspect ratio</p>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Text<br/>More text<br/>Lots of text
  </div>
  <div class="button_container">
    <div class="button second_case">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="button second_case">
      B
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br/>
<p>Default</p>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    Text<br/>More text<br/>Lots of text
  </div>
  <div class="button_container">
    <div class="button third_case">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="button third_case">
      B
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-br-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.